# Java Program to write text file, using separator, and in first line write record number

Tags: java

I am trying to write in file, I need to write total number of the record in first line, and in while loop write all other line, everything working good but, in first line need to write total number of the record how can i do that, Please help me!! Thanks!!

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;


public class headerline {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         File folderall = new File("FilesIn1");
         File[] BFFileall = folderall.listFiles();

         for (final File file : BFFileall) {

                String str = file.getName();

                BufferedReader br = null;

                 BufferedWriter lbwp = null; 
                 BufferedWriter lb = null;

                try {

                    int lbwpcount = 1;
                    int lbcount = 1;

                     String reprintbwletterbwpca = (str);
                     lbwp = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(reprintbwletterbwpca));
                     lbwp.write("Total line number: " + lbwpcount);

                     String reprintbwletterbwpcalb = (str);
                     lb = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(reprintbwletterbwpcalb));
                     lb.write("Total line number: " + lbwpcount);

                     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                     String line;
                     line = br.readLine();



                     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                            String[] actionID = line.split("|");

                            String actionid  = actionID[2];
                            String custnumber = actionID[3];

                            lbwp.write("ActionID: " + actionid + ",CustomerNumber: " + custnumber + "\r\n");
                            lbwpcount++;
                            lb.write("ActionID: " + actionid + ",CustomerNumber: " + custnumber + "\r\n");
                            lbcount++;
                    }
                     lbwp.close();
                     lb.close();

                } catch(Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }   

         }

    }

}
```

suppose file has 1201 lines, it should print 
Total line number: 1200, in first line. 
than
"ActionID: " + actionid + ",CustomerNumber: " + custnumber
..........

suppose other file has 1451 lines, it should print 
Total line number: 1450, in first line. 
than
"ActionID: " + actionid + ",CustomerNumber: " + custnumber
..........

I have no idea how can i do that, please help me!! can i write first line as last after finish while loop??
Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `java.nio.file` package. It has class `Files` which has a method [readAllLines(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29). This will read all lines and add it to a `List`. Simply use `List.size()` to get number of lines, and write it to another file as you wanted :-)

Try this program, this will let you know the number of lines in the file :

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.List;

public class ReadAndWriteFile {

    private Path actualPath;
    private Path sourcePath;

    private BufferedReader reader;
    private BufferedWriter writer;

    private List<String> lines;

    public ReadAndWriteFile() {
        sourcePath = Paths.get("xanadu.txt");
        //sourcePath = sourcePath.toAbsolutePath();
        actualPath = Paths.get("xanadu_new.txt");
        //targetPath = actualPath.toAbsolutePath();

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

        try {   
            lines = Files.readAllLines(sourcePath, charset);
            System.out.println("Number of Lines : " + lines.size());
            reader = Files.newBufferedReader(sourcePath, charset);
            writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(actualPath, charset);

            String message = "Total Line Number : " + lines.size();
            writer.write(String.format("%s%n", message));
            for (String line : lines) {
                System.out.println(line);
                writer.write(String.format("%s%n", line));
            }
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReadAndWriteFile();
    }
}
```

Text File (xanadu.txt) Contents :

```
In Xanadu did Kubla Khan
A stately pleasure-dome decree:
Where Alph, the sacred river, ran
Through caverns measureless to man
Down to a sunless sea.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a high level explanation:

1. Loop through all the lines and store it in a `List<Record>`.
2. Write the total number of elements in your `List<Record>` as the first line (this will be total number of records)
3. In a loop, write the record data to the rest of the file

Since you need the total *first*, that means you've gotta loop once to find out what the total is.  Then loop again to write the records.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand you properly can you explain little more?? please.. thanks!!

Comment: @user2726811 what are you confused about?

Comment: first get total line numbers and than array it?? than write into first line??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know the total line number until you have read all the lines of the file.

Some options available to you are:

1. **Read the file twice.** The first time, simply keep a count the number of lines. Print it. Then  read the file a second time, and write our the records like you are doing at the moment.
2. **Hold the records in memory temporarily.** As you read the file, keep the content in a collection (e.g. `ArrayList`) and write it out at the end. You can use `list.size()` to get the number of records. You could use use Apache Commons `FileUtils.readLines()` to do this, if you don't mind introducing a JAR dependency. EDIT: Or write your own method (see below).
3. **Prepend the record count afterwards.** Write out the file then as you are doing then *prepend* the record count to the file.
4. **Challenge the requirements.** Ask if it is *really* necessary to output the record count at the start? Could it be omitted? Could it be at the end? Etc.

Here's some sample code for option 2 - a method for reading the file into a list that you can manipulate:

```
public static List<String> readLines(File file) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
File file = new File("example.txt");
List<String> lines = readLines(file);

int lineCount = lines.size();
// TODO: Write out the line count

for (String line : lines) {
    // TODO: Process the line
}
```

Comment: I need to write in first line, I thought to create another while loop, I think that's not proper way to do, is there any other way to do it?? Please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: I have given four options, take your pick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache Commons [FileUtils.readLines()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29). This returns you all lines in your original file as a list, from which you can get the size.

Otherwise you would have to read all the lines manually to count them first and then write them to the file.